# New to programming, learning python. Trying to get this program to work

Tags: python, counter

First, a link to the "problem":

http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/thinkcspy/Labs/montepi.html

I'm doing good up until getting a counter set up. I feel confident in doing the rest once I've gotten that figured out.

```
import turtle
import math
import random

fred = turtle.Turtle()
fred.shape("circle")

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setworldcoordinates(-1,-1,1,1)

def main():

    count = 0

    def ifDist():
        if fred.distance(0,0) > 1:
            fred.color("blue")
        else:
            fred.color("red")
            counter()   

    def counter():
        count = count + 1
        return count

    def darts():
        numdarts = 2
        for i in range(numdarts):
            randx = random.random()
            randy = random.random()

            x = randx
            y = randy

            fred.penup()
            fred.goto(randx, randy)
            ifDist()
            fred.stamp()
            fred.goto(randx, -randy)
            ifDist()
            fred.stamp()
            fred.goto(-randx, randy)
            ifDist()
            fred.stamp()
            fred.goto(-randx, -randy)
            ifDist()
            fred.stamp()

    darts()

    print(count)

main()


wn.exitonclick()
```

It keeps printing 0 for the counter. I've been trying at this for a couple days (at least this code doesn't give an error message...) and I'm sure it's a simple fix, but I just don't know what it would be. Any assistance would really be appreciated.

EDIT: included counter() in the else statement, as I had previously done when tinkering with it. It now calls the counter, but I do get an error as well:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Google Drive\School\PYTHON\5_16_piEstimator.py", line 53, in 
    main()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Google Drive\School\PYTHON\5_16_piEstimator.py", line 49, in main
    darts()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Google Drive\School\PYTHON\5_16_piEstimator.py", line 37, in darts
    ifDist()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Google Drive\School\PYTHON\5_16_piEstimator.py", line 20, in ifDist
    counter()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Google Drive\School\PYTHON\5_16_piEstimator.py", line 23, in counter
    count = count + 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment

Comment: Unless you call `count=counter()` it won't increment, and I suspect calling `counter` at all will throw an exception, since count is used before it is bound inside counter.

Comment: @Perkins, you would be correct about `counter()` raising an exception if it were declared at the module level, but since it's declared inside the `main()` function, it gets all of main's locals in a closure.

Comment: @ACEfanatic02, you still have the same problem. You can't rebind the reference outside your scope without declaring it `global` or `nonlocal`

Comment: Thanks gnibbler, I couldn't remember the declaration for letting you bind names from a parent scope, I just knew there would be a problem.  The first line of counter should read `nonlocal count` to tell it that you intend to redefine count from the parent scope.  Note that nonlocal is new in python3, in python2.7 it will raise an exception for invalid syntax if you try to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from not calling your `counter()` function, this won't work anyway.

As @Perkins mentioned in the comments, you can't modify a reference outside of your scope. You can't increment `count` because `int` are immutable in Python. `count = count + 1` is creating a new `int` object and discarding the old one. The new instance needs to be bound to the count variable

Assuming Python3, you can say count is "nonlocal"

```
def counter():
    nonlocal count
    count = count + 1
    return count
```

which will tell Python it's ok to change the binding of count in `main` instead of trying to use a local (to counter) variable called count

Comment: Awesome! This simple thing is just what I needed. Didn't know about using nonlocal but I've got this bug ironed out for now. It's all a learning process. Thanks a ton!

Comment: "If you give a man a fish he eats for a day, if you give a man a gun pointed at his foot he doesn't learn proper scoping" - _source unknown_

Answer (score 1):

Your counter function is never called, hence the count never increments.

Comment: Oops, you got here first. I'll delete my answer!